# React Isomorphic setup and Node ES6 syntax issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have included two questions here, the two questions will be at the end of this post.

=================>>> **Background** <<<=================

I'm trying to test out react isomorphic way, and I setup a server.js and I install the following node modules

my node version node: '0.12.0'

```
"babel": "^4.7.16",
"babel-core": "^4.7.16",
"babel-loader": "^4.2.0",
"babel-runtime": "^4.7.16",
"node-jsx": "^0.12.4",
```

**The following is my server.js  ( partial )**

```
require("babel/register")({experimental: true});
require('node-jsx').install({extension:'.jsx'});

var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var React = require('react');
var EntryPointComponent = React.createFactory(require('./router.jsx'));

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var component = EntryPointComponent();
    var html = React.renderToString(component);
    res.send(html);
});

server.listen(port);
```

**And below is example routes.jsx  ( partial, it will be include in router.jsx )**

```
var React  = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    {Route, NotFoundRoute} = Router,
    App = require('./app'),
    DefaultHandler = require('./pages/test');

module.exports = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route name="test" handler={DefaultHandler} path="/test" addHandlerKey={true} />
    <NotFoundRoute handler={DefaultHandler} />
  </Route>
)
```

**The following is router.jsx**

```
var React  = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    routes = require('./routes');


Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById("content"));
});
```

=================>>> **Problem** <<<=================

when I try to run the following command

```
node server.js --harmony
```

It will throw me Unexpected token issue

```
/blah/blah/blah/routes.jsx:3
    {Route, NotFoundRoute} = Router,
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

=================>>> **Questions** <<<=================

1. Looks like the Node didn't recognize the ES6 syntax,  and I try to include "babel",  am I use it correctly??  Or how to make Node understand ES6 syntax ??
2. Is the above a correct way to setup isomorphic react app ?? Or what would be the correct / recommended way to setup the react app in isomorphic way ??

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are 'overriding' babel loader by using 'node-jsx'. [Docs](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/02/23/babel-loves-react/).

```
//"there can be only one!" :)
require("babel/register")({experimental: true});

//to be removed
//require('node-jsx').install({extension:'.jsx'});
```

Answer (score -3):

Both Node.js and io.js doesn't support ES6 destructuring assignment yet.